# How can i copy the blob file created to wwwroot folder of appservice (here my web applications resides) using azure function app?

Tags: azure, function

i have created a function app using blob trigger. The purpose of this function is whenever the blob created, it has to transfer/copy the file from blob storage container to appservice wwwrrootfolder where my web application resides.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Is this just to stage code attached to a release pipeline?  If not it may not be a good idea because if your function app is deleted and recreate all that data will be lost. Or if the function needs to be scaled to a different region at a later date then they'd need to be synced across the instances.

Comment: I am trying to copy a file from blob storage to the folder in my web application once i uploaded to blob.

Comment: Why not have the web app read the file(s) in the blob?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly using Azure Function, but I think the easiest way is using Logic Apps + Blob Trigger and FTP connectors:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/

Comment: I tried using logic app to connect to blob trigger when the file created, but, couldn't find the way to copy that blob file and save it to the folder in my web application.

Comment: there are two approaches described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680775/1384539